# R: Plot aggregated frequency depending on chosen category-criterion

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate, categories

I have some dataset with one column being the "Exposure", one the "number of events" and several columns labeling various category-types.

```
 Exposure<-c(10,2.1,2.8,4.5,21)
 NoEvents <- c(1,0,2,0,0)
 Cat1<-as.factor(c("A","A","B","A","B"))
 Cat2<-as.factor(c("X","Y","Y","Y","X"))
 Cat3<-as.factor(c("u","v","u","w","w"))
 dataTest<-data.frame(Exposure,NoEvents,Cat1,Cat2,Cat3)
 dataTest


    Exposure     NoEvents        Cat1         Cat2        Cat3
    10.0         1               A            X            u
    2.1          0               A            Y            v
    2.8          2               B            Y            u
    4.5          0               A            Y            w
    21.0         0               B            X            w
```

I would like now to (flexibly) calculate and plot the frequency (NoEvents/Exposure) aggregated for the chosen category-type: Cat1, Cat2 or Cat3. For a fixed category-column, e.g. Cat1, I can define the following function

```
freq_Cat <- function(data,Cat1){
  data_aggr<-aggregate(. ~ Cat1, data[,c("Exposure","NoEvents","Cat1")], sum)
  data_aggr[,"frequency"] <- data_aggr$NoEvents/data_aggr$Exposure
  return(data_aggr)
}
```

and then plot it by

```
 ggplot(freq_Cat(dataTest,Cat1), aes(x=Cat1,y=frequency)) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="dodgerblue",col="black")
```

I would like to make the function freq_Cat as well the plotting more flexible, so that I flexibly can choose by which category-type/column (Cat1, Cat2 or Cat3) to aggregate without just copy-paste and replace Cat1 by another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass in the category as a number, you can compute the variable to use.

```
freq_Cat <- function(data,Cat){
  Var  = paste("Cat", Cat, sep="")
  Form = formula(paste(". ~", Var))
  data_aggr<-aggregate(Form, data[,c("Exposure","NoEvents",Var)], sum)
  data_aggr[,"frequency"] <- data_aggr$NoEvents/data_aggr$Exposure
  return(data_aggr)
}
```

But now instead of calling it as you did use something like

```
freq_Cat(dataTest, Cat=1)
```

Alternatively, if you want to refer to the category variable by name you could use:

```
freq_Cat <- function(data,Cat){
  Form = formula(paste(". ~", Cat))
  data_aggr<-aggregate(Form, data[,c("Exposure","NoEvents",Cat)], sum)
  data_aggr[,"frequency"] <- data_aggr$NoEvents/data_aggr$Exposure
  return(data_aggr)
}
```

and then access the function like this:

```
freq_Cat(dataTest, Cat="Country")
```

Comment: Thank you. And how would I go about this, if the categories have entirely different names, e.g. „Country“, „wealth level“, „language“, and if I don’t want to rename them?